# How to call a PL/SQL Function inside a Trigger?

Tags: oracle

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INSERT_DATACOL
  2  AFTER insert ON FIELDWORKER_INFO for each row 
  3  declare
  4  FW NUMBER;
  5  begin 
  6  FW := datacol_insert_fwkr(:OLD.FIELDWORKER); 
  7  end; 
  8  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for TRIGGER INSERT_DATACOL:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/1      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
4/7      PLS-00201: identifier 'DATACOL_INSERT_FWKR' must be declared
```

Comment: datacol_insert_fwkr is a function? `identifier 'DATACOL_INSERT_FWKR' must be declared` means either function doesn't exist or it could be a permission issue whether you have access to that function.

Comment: Check whether you have access to the function or function exists in your schema?

Comment: Thanks Polppan.. The trigger was existing but it was a permission issue.

Comment: Polppan - the trigger got complied successfully .. but when isert a NEW ROW in FIELDWORKER_INFO .. then the statemnets inside the functions are not getting executed :((

Comment: I suggest you open another question for your recent problem as this is already closed.